# MS Access Query Designer Best Way To View SQL Server Tables

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, ms-access, query-designer

I have to write many complex queries involving MS Access tables joining SQL Server tables.

To write the queries quickly it would be helpful to be able to add SQL server tables from the show table dialog box in the query designer.

Apparently I have to link each SQL server table manually before it will show or write the query free hand using passthrough queries. Am I missing something obvious? Is there an easier way to add all sql server tables at once?

I do not like linked tables due to performance issues. All I need is the query syntax to add to the vba editor.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Can you link the tables, write your queries, and then remove the links?  I suspect I'm missing something, too, because I don't understand how the queries would be useable after the links are gone.  But it seems like that's what you want.  (?)

Comment: Thanks HansUp. Thats exactly what I'm doing I was just hoping find a faster way. All I really need is the query syntax to enter into a VBA Editor. Its just a pain to keep linking an de-linking tables as I go. I can write the queries freehand but it helps to see the tables in the  query editor = it helps with inner-join syntax.